# Django CSRF. Can I POST from subdomain to main domain?

Tags: django, ssl, csrf, subdomain

I have looked at similar discussions but can't seem to find an answer to my question.

I'm working on an app in which each account will have their own instance served on a subdomain. 
http://account.myawesomeapp.com.

The users will login from this page and the login form will be posted to 
https://myawesomeapp.com/my_login_view/ 
afterwards I will do some username/account hashing, and db. auth session things and redirect to:
http://account.myawesomeapp.com/registration/handoff// - which will then login the user and delete the auth session entry.

However. Although I have set CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN to '.myawesomeapp.com', I get an CSRF error when posting from the subdomain to the main domain?

I this not possible? Will I have to create a special subdomain for my SSL login needs?

I hope my question makes sense and that I've not messed up in the django terms and conventions :)

UPDATE:

I found this blog entry: 
http://zachsnow.com/#!/blog/2012/django-subdomains-csrf-and-https/

Will that method work? Is it safe?

UPDATE 2:

Tried Zachs approach and it didn't work... 
I keep getting this error:

Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.

Comment: Did you add `csrf_token` to your POST request?

Comment: sorry. forgot to mention that. yeah the csrf token is there and is being posted just fine :-S

Comment: `I get an CSRF error`, what error? Provide exact details if you need to debug anything. *Never* ignore error messages.

Comment: Sorry. The error I'm getting is "CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Comment: have you set your CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-domain

Comment: I think the problem is that CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN and SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN were both set to '.localhost'. Apparently this doesn't work in browsers(?).